# Minecraft FTB Agrarian Skies 1 without entering the Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

(Yes, I know that this map/modpack is 10 years old. I'm on a bit of a trip playing through old packs right now.)

The "We must go Deeper." quest in Agrarian Skies 1 (version 4.1.0) says, "Please note you do not have to go to the Nether. This map can be completed without ever entering the Nether." Is this true, and if so for what meaning of "completed"?

Clearly it's not possible to finish every single quest without ever entering the Nether, since the "Highway to Hell" quest following "We must go Deeper." literally asks you to go to the Nether. But even that quest says "You don't have to go to the Nether," so maybe it's possible to finish (almost) everything else without it.

Reading this, I made it my goal to try and finish the modpack without going to the Nether, but I'm starting to doubt this is fully possible (without relying on luck from reward bags, at least). For example,

- How would you obtain the various Nether ores required for the "Raw Ores" quest?
- How would I get Aura Nodes? I read that they're also supposed to be around Y level 3 in the Overworld, but so far I've had no luck finding them. (EDIT: Nevermind, I found some now. Looks like I was looking a bit too close to the void.)
- How would I get Infernal bees? I *think* those are not strictly necessary, but they would certainly make things a lot easier.

So, is there anyone other than me who's crazy enough to play AS1 in 2024 that knows more about this?